# Xcode 8 memory graph malloc stack can't load backtrace

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, xcode8

I'm using the memory graph in Xcode 8.1 and cannot see the backtrace, just the memory addresses. I have already opened the 'Malloc Stack'.

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I am also experiencing this issue. It is a shame that nobody has replied.

Comment: This is a bug of Xcode; But the good news is that the Xcode 8.1 beta has fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Check that the DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT build setting for your current configuration (Debug presumably) is set to **dwarf with dsym**. That could be the reason of the missing symbols.